# Bash - can't use command 'bc' since Bandizip have the command with same name

Tags: bash

I trying to use Linux bc to do division between two float number, but it throw an error, and I realize when I run bc, it execute Bandizip command

```
$ bc
bc 6.08(Alpha) - Bandizip Command line tool. Copyright(C) 2011-2017 Bandisoft
Usage:
  bc <command> [<switches>...] <archive> [<files>...] [<path_to_extract>]

<Commands>
  a : Add files to archive
  x : eXtract files with full pathname
  t : Test integrity of archive
  d : Delete files from archive
  c : Create new archive(or overwrite exist file)
  e : Extract files without directory names

<Switches>
  -             Stop switches scanning
  -l:<0...9>    Set compression level (0:store, 5:default, 9:maximal)
  -r-           Disable recursion (default)
  -r            Enable recurse subdirectories
  -aoa          Overwrite All existing files without prompt
  -aos          Skip extracting of existing files
  -aou          aUto rename extracting file
                (for example, name.txt will be renamed to name (2).txt)
  -sfx:[{name}] Create SFX archive
  -zopfli       Use Zopfli as deflate compressor(very slow)
  -p:{password} Set password
  -o:{dir}      Specify target folder
  -y            Assume Yes on all queries
  -fmt:{fmt}    Specify archive format
                (zip, zipx, exe, tar, tgz, lzh, iso, 7z, gz, xz)
  -v:{size}     Specify volume size(-v:1000000 -v:1440k -v:100MB ...)
  -target:auto  Extract to target path smartly
  -target:name  Extract to archive-name folder of target path
```

I can't uninstall bandizip and can't use other command to divide two float number since I already have lot function write by using bc

How to solve this problem?

Comment: replace in script to the full name of `bc` command. and yes, you can replace `bc` use with sample `awk` program

Comment: Hi, may I know more about how to replace in script to the full name of bc command?

Comment: Write `/usr/bin/bc` instead ob `bc`.

Comment: Run `which bc` or `whereis bc` to get a list of all possible alternatives.

Comment: File a bug report with Bandisoft for conflicting with a POSIX-standard tool name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the bc application have to exists in at least two different directories.

It seems to me like the PATH variable from your shell or system is configured wrong so it first finds the *wrong* bc application first.

You can print the PATH variable from your shell, for example:

```
# echo $PATH
/usr/gnu/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/ucb:/bin:/usr/bin
```

As you can see, there is a colon (:) separated list of paths which are searched when you type in a command (relatively).

This means, for the above path, your shell (e.g. bash) searches for your command in the following order, until it was found:

1. /usr/gnu/bin
2. /usr/local/bin
3. /usr/ucb
4. /bin
5. /usr/bin

If the command could not be found, you should see something like this:

```
# pacman
pacman: Command not found.
```

Due it is more obvious that *bc* is the calculator, you should ensure that the path which contains the calculator *bc* is listed before the other path in the PATH variable.

Very sure the person who installed *Bandizip Command* put the path in the global shell configuration, e.g. `/etc/profile`.

Comment: `PATH` doesn't necessarily have to be *wrong*, just inconveniently configured. Providing a tool whose name conflicts with a [utility required by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/bc.html) is the real problem.

Comment: Hi, after I try the command echo $PATH, I found that bandizip directory is come before the real bc directory, so because of this whenever I run bc it will execute the bandizip command?

Comment: It also could be possible, that bc from bandizip is installed somewhere, where it used before the calculator bc.

On my system /usr/local/bin comes before /usr/bin

Since I can't analyze the system, i'm just guessing arround.

Comment: problem solve after I edit the PATH variable to change the order, thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @jialeko ensure you have it fixed so that it works for everyone else on the system

Comment: If i had to maintain/install this software on machines, I definitly would rename the bc command shipped from bandizip, because as mention from @chepner, the bc calculator is such a standard tool, used in various shellscripts, which will definitly cause, sooner or later, to real hard to find problems.